# Cannot get mockImplementation to work for mocked module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to properly test this File, however osme test can be done when mocking entirre module, but some i need only specific methods mocked , so i tried combinaitons of multiple things, but currently one way I am attemping to do this is for this one test below

// features.js

```
const getFeature = (featureFlag) => {
  const client = getFeatureInstance();

  const feature = client.getFeature(featureFlag);

  return retrieveFeature(feature);
};
```

`getFeatureInstance` and `retrieveFeature` are local to same file, `client` is something i need to manually implement in the mock returned by getFeatureInstance

// features.unit.spec.js

```
const {
    getFeatureInstance,
  } = require('../../../../../src/server/features');

jest.mock('../../../../../src/server/features');


describe('server:apis:feature:management', () => {
    it('should return feature', () => {
      // jest.resetAllMocks();
      const management = jest.requireActual('../../../../../src/server/features');
      const _featureId = 'FAKE-FEATURE';
  
      getFeatureInstance.mockImplementation(() => ({
        getFeature: jest.fn(featureId => ({ featureId }))
      }));
  
      const feature = management.getFeature(_featureId);
  
      console.log(feature);
  
    });
  });
```

But no matter what I do, any method of testing, mocking implementaion of local modules doesnt work.

if you look at `getFeatureInstance.`mockImplementation`, it does not return what i am telling it too, I went and logged the objects in the actual` features.js` and in the test File.

Even if i remove `getFeatureInstance.mockImplementation` , the objects dont change.

From what i see, the mocking of the module works but no `mockImplementation` does anything per test

Now if I mocked the entire module and set the method in the factory, it works but i need different implementations per test

Answer (score 0):

Did you try spying?

```js
import * as features from '../../../../../src/server/features';

it('should return feature', () => {
  spyOn(features, 'getFeatureInstance').mockReturnValue({
    getFeature: jest.fn(featureId => ({ featureId }))
  });
  
  const feature = management.getFeature(_featureId);
...
```

Comment: no luck :(, the mocking is working but implementation is not so it just returns null

Comment: `getFeature` and `getFeatureInstance` needs to be in separate files. If both methods are in the same file then mocking won't work.

Comment: Ah! that was it marek. I do hate that about js unit testing but that was it, thanks man